# Sending data to main/calling activity without startActivityForResult/onActivityResult?

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to send data to the main/calling `activity` without ?`startActivityForResult/onActivityResult`? I start an `activity` and don't expect a result from it. But there are situations in which I'd like to inform the calling `activity` that the started `activity` didn't finish it's job.

Since I don't expect the `activity` to fail doing it's job I think `startActivityForResult/onActivityResult` is the wrong approach.

Comment: you can pass one of these in the Intent extras:  Messenger, ResultReceiver or custom Binder

Comment: I would appreciate if persons would explain their downvotes.

Comment: honestly,  if your child activity never returns so your parent activity will never be seen, maybe its the reason for downvoting?

Comment: But the child activity returns if it couldn't finish it's job. E.g. if the user presses back accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of approach you should be using

```
startActivityForResult/onActivityResult
```

but incase you wish for an alternate approach ,you could use `SharedPreferences` to store flag or key pair values which the the ***called*** activity can set and ***calling*** activity can check.

Comment: But then again I would have to check for the `SharedPreferences` every time. So the app is doing unnecessary work most of the time. But it seems there is no other way than `startActivityForResult/onActivityResult` or some workaround with `SharedPreferences` or something like that.

Comment: well you woudln't be checking `SP` 'always' rather only once you call the new activity and when onResume() of the caller activity is called. 

But since you disapprove of it, Why not create an `interface` in the called activity and let the caller activity implement it  and then pass a reference to the called activity.

Comment: @Kurztipp i gave you three solutions,  did you try any?

Comment: @Kurztipp ok, two: Binder was a stupid idea, it is also working but it requires api 18+ and is complex in use

Comment: @Kurztipp the third approach (with Binder) can be simplified a lot using AIDL though... i didn't test it but it should work exactly in the same way as service AIDL work

Comment: @pskink: Dude keep it simple.Just to pass a flag value from an activity to another ,your asking him to implement AIDL.

Comment: @root flag? what flag? btw what is complex in AIDL? it was designed for remote procedure calling as if they were local calls,  all the messy code is generated by aidl compiler and you don't see it at all

Comment: @pskink OP mentioned he just needs to inform a calling activity in his application. Flag was indicative of what OP asked to let the calling activity know of success/failure.I don't see an RPC here as these are just two activities communicating with themselves.